# Can I call a virtual function in a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual

I know that a call of virtual function in constructors can cause undefined behavior.
However, calling virtual function with a scope modifier is OK?

```
class A
{

public:
A() { A::f(); }
virtual void f();

};

class B
{

public:
B() { B::f(); }
virtual void f();

};
```

I think it is not different from calling a non-virtual function and it doesn't have any problems.
Is it right? Or Did I overlook something?

Comment: You can, but it won't do virtual dispatch. I haven't heard of UB being caused just by calling them normally, though.

Comment: There is nothing undefined about the behavior of a virtual call from a constructor.

Comment: Note: Calling a virtual function in a constructor is no undefined behavior (It may be unexpected)

Comment: @chris: There may be undefined behavior if you call a pure virtual function that has no implementation...

Comment: @MooingDuck, Very true.

Comment: @chris It *will* call them virtually, but the VFT has only been built up to the current class, so it won't call any method in a derived class.

Comment: Or if you call a virtual function via a "sibling" class (not via `this`) to the class being constructed / destroyed, that can be UB.

Comment: @chris: `Derived::Derived() { Base* b = this; b->f(); }` may call `Derived::f()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are OK with your calls to `A::f()` in `A::A()` and to `B::f()` in `B::B()`. The virtual call mechanism is not used when the functions are called with explicit qualification.

This is what the draft standard says about using explicit qualification when calling a virtual function:

> 10.3/15 Explicit qualification with the scope operator (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism. [ Example:

```
class B { public: virtual void f(); };
class D : public B { public: void f(); };
void D::f() { / ... / B::f(); }
```

> Here, the function call in `D::f` really does call `B::f` and not `D::f`. —end example ]

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine, with the understanding that it will behave exactly as if you were calling a non-virtual function. I assume this is your intent.